# PySpark + Dataproc - Can't get more than X executors and X GB/Ram per executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I use a Dataproc cluster to lemmatize strings using Spark NLP.

My cluster has 5 nodes + 1 master, each of the worker nodes has 16CPU + 64GB RAM.

Doing some maths, my ideal Spark config is:

- spark.executor.instances = 14
- spark.executor.cores = 5
- spark.executor.memory = 19G

With that conf, I maximize the usage of the machines and have enough room for ApplicationManager and Off-Heap memory.

However when creating the SparkSession with

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName('perf-test-extract-skills') \
    .config("spark.default.parallelism", "140") \
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "19G") \
    .config("spark.executor.memoryOverhead", "1361m") \
    .config("spark.driver.memoryOverhead", "1361m") \
    .config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true") \
    .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false") \
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "14") \
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "5") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "19G") \
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.26.0,com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.12:4.1.0') \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I can only get 10 workers with 10Gib RAM on each as shown on the screenshot below:
[image: spark]

I tried editing the parameter `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` to 64000 to let yarn manage nodes with up to 64GB RAM but it's still the same, I can't go beyond the 10 workers and 10GB RAM.

Also, when I check the values in the "environment" tab, everything looks ok and the values are set according to my SparkSession config, meaning that the master did a request but it cannot be fullfiled ?

Is there something I forgot or are my maths wrong ?

EDIT: I managed to increase the number of executors with the new SparkSession I shared above. I can now get 14 executors but each executor is still using 10GB Ram when it should use 19.

Here is one of my executors, is it using 19GB of RAM ? I don't really understand the meaning of the different "memory" columns.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false`?

Comment: Tried to disable it but it's still the same.

Comment: Did you check YARN resource manager metrics? Especially resource usage and pending memory.

Comment: Can you try  setting parameters during spark submit?

Comment: @ozlemg I don't think it is the problem, when I check the `environment` tab on Yarn Resources Monitor, I can see all the varibles are set well, it can't just apply the parameters.

Comment: Hi @Agudolive, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.